# Hide/Show HTML inner table in button click using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried hide and show html inner table using jquery. I want to hide the table when page loads then after click search button , table will show with values.

But the below code is hidding intially, after click the search button, its blinking and hiding again.Please advise what is the wrong here.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

 $("#historylist").hide();

$("#historysearch").click(function() {
 $("#historylist").show();
});
// }
});    

<table id="searchTbl" width="800" >
<tr>
<td valign="top">Release No</td>
<td valign="top">
<input type="text" name="releaseNo" value="" style="width:200" />
</td>
<td valign="top"><input type="button" value="Search" onClick="commit()" style="width:80" id="historysearch"/></td>
</tr>
<br /><br />
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" id="historylist">
<tr>
<th><font size="-1">Header1</font></th>
<th><font size="-1">Header2</font></th>
<th><font size="-1">Header3</font></th>
<th><font size="-1">Header4</font></th> 
<th><font size="-1">Header5</font></th>


</tr>
</table>
</table>

function commit(){

        document.menu.cmd.value='search';
        document.menu.submit();
    }
```

Comment: you call the `commit()` function onclick, please check that function.

Comment: show() and hide() is correct. Can you post the code in commit()?

Comment: you cannot have table/br as a child of a table it is working fine if you solve that http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3QV49/1/

Comment: it should works fine just remove the onClick since you are using Jquery to run the check.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: That's not the point. Even if you embed a table inside a table, the jQuery is also fine. I suspect that `commit()` function has done something.

Comment: @ArunPJohny: maybe but he/she is still silent. We cannot help more.

Comment: @Han yes I think we can leave it here

Comment: function commit(){

  document.menu.cmd.value='search';
  document.menu.submit();
 }

Comment: @ArunPJohny Sorry for delay..I have posted the commit function , please advise.

Comment: that is the problem because you are refreshing the page...

Comment: @ArunPJohny Okay, Any idea to achieve my target ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this,

```
  function commit(){         
      $("#historylist").toggle();
  }
```